# JSF doesn't interpreted in seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Hy guys,

I installed jboss-seam on weblogic 10.3 (with many problem :( ) but now it's work, my application is deployed.

But now, I have a new problem, my JSF isn't interpreted and the JSF code appears in HTML.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
 <listener>
   <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


   <!-- RichFaces -->

   <context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
      <param-value>glassX</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <!-- Suppress spurious stylesheets -->

   <context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
      <param-value>disable</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name>
      <param-value>disable</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <!-- Change load strategy to DEFAULT to disable sending scripts/styles as packs -->

   <context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
      <param-value>ALL</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
      <param-value>ALL</param-value>
   </context-param>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>


   <!-- Facelets development mode (disable in production) -->

   <context-param>
      <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
      <param-value>@debug@</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <!-- JSF -->

   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.seam</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/AuthenticatorAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.Authenticator</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/BookingListAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.BookingList</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/RegisterAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.Register</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/ChangePasswordAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.ChangePassword</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/HotelBookingAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.HotelBooking</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/HotelSearchingAction/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.example.booking.HotelSearching</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>jboss-seam-jee5/EjbSynchronizations/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

My FacesServlet is load in startup but JSF doesn't work.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand how do you use Seam and, at the same time, declare EJB references in web.xml file. Seam Takes care of inject any EJB once you enable Seam EJB interceptor.

Comment: This declaration is mandatory to be compatible with weblogic. It's in the doc so I think is good ;)

Comment: Are you sure `@debug@` works in web.xml?

Comment: I don't know, I copy this from the doc ^^. I'm new in J2EE so I don't understand all config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And now, it's working.

Answer (score 2):

If the XHTML page is not been parsed by the `FacesServlet`, then it simply means that the request URL did not match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. You have set its `url-pattern` to `*.seam` So, to open the JSF page, you should not invoke it by http://example.com/page.xhtml, but by http://example.com/page.seam.

By the way, the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` sets the **actual** file extension of template files where JSF should look for and parse. You've set it to `.seam` as well, but this should really be `.xhtml`.

Comment: The `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` should be set to the **actual** file extension of the template files. This is *usually* `.xhtml`. But if you're really using template files with `.seam` extension, then let it so. I then only question why you're then able to view the XHTML files "plain vanilla". You should have gotten a 404 page not found. You really need to supply more information: 1) what are the **actual** file extensions? 2) what extension did you use in the request URL (in the browser's address bar)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help, but here is our web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<!-- Ajax4jsf -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--
    This config will enforce the container to compress all the richfaces
    resources including images, stylesheets, javascript to be compressed
    before sending to client. It will make significant reduced load time.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Seam -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>UTF8 Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>foo.bar.filter.UTF8Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UTF8 Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Facelets development mode (disable in production) -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/kf.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.csv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Job executor servlet for jBPM Timers -->
<!-- TODO: Restrict access or better switch to ejb3 TimerService -->
<servlet>
    <description>
        This servlet has the purpose of executing pending jobs.
    </description>
    <servlet-name>JobExecutorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jbpm.job.executor.JobExecutorServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JobExecutorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jobs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.document.DocumentStoreServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: One thing is strange. In the monitoring servlet, I see "Invocation Total Count" of my FacesServlet increase every time a page load. But the jsf is not interpreted. It's very strange...